# Tensorflow matrix multiplication is slower than numpy

Tags: numpy, tensorflow, gpu

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from time import time

def print_timer(func):
  start_time = time()
  func()
  end_time = time()
  print(end_time - start_time)

N = 4
A = np.random.randn(N, 1000, 16000)
B = np.random.randn(N, 16000, 10)
sess = tf.Session()


A_ = tf.constant(A)
B_ = tf.constant(B)

def np_test():
  r = np.empty([N, 1000, 10])
  for i in range(N):
    r[i] = np.matmul(A[i], B[i])

print_timer(lambda: np.matmul(A, B))
print_timer(lambda: sess.run(tf.matmul(A,B)))
```

When I ran this code, I got the result as below:

```
1.3403866291046143
4.291470527648926
```

which are the running time.

I don't know why tensorflow.matmul is slower than numpy.matmul.
I am running this code on the P40 NVIDIA GPU and the tensorflow version I am using is 1.4.

When I tried running this code on tensorflow 1.8, I got the same result.

If tensorflow runs matrix multiplication in parallel, shouldn't the run times for the matrix multiplication on the GPU be much faster than those that are run on numpy, which are run on the CPU?

Comment: Isn't it possible that copying data to the CPU adds a big overhead? I would try with a longer operation, for instance 100000 matrix multiplications. I might be completely wrong.

Comment: Do the same with `A, B = tf.get_variable('v0', initializer=A), ...` and be prepared for a surprise (no cudaMemcpy).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `tf.matmul` inside the evaluation, meaning that you are mearuring the time of the creation of the operation together with its computation time.

Try this instead:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()

N = 4
A = np.random.randn(N, 1000, 16000)
B = np.random.randn(N, 16000, 10)
A_ = tf.constant(A)
B_ = tf.constant(B)

AB_ = A_ @ B_

%timeit np.matmul(A, B)
%timeit sess.run(AB_)
```

Some remarks:

- Don't reinvent the wheel, use `timeit` to measure computatio times.
- You can use `@` as a shortcut for matrix multiplication since python 3.5.

Answer (score 0):

You're not using the constant tensors that you've created. Change this:

```
print_timer(lambda: sess.run(tf.matmul(A,B)))
```

to this:

```
print_timer(lambda: sess.run(tf.matmul(A_,B_)))
```